# Change Thread.Priority to make program more responsive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multithreading

I have written a .net winforms application that does some heavy processing and slows my computer down pretty much. I have read something about

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority
```

but i dont really understand if i should give the main thread more priority or to lower its priority to remove the "lagging" and the slowing of my computer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends entirely what your application and any additional threads are doing.  You shouldn't really boost your UI thread priority, however you could lower any background thread priorities.

To keep the UI responsive, don't do any heavy processing on that thread - do the work on a background thread.

It's a bit vague perhaps, but then so if your question.  Happy to go into more detail if you can too.  Hope that helps !

Comment: Well i think i need to remove the process from the main UI and put it in a different thread. That might solve but i just though that Thread.CurrentThread.Priority would solve that problem.

Comment: Well here is another question then, how can i create a thread and keep it alive even though all code is done? Because the processesing is not done directly , but after some time and i can do it in a thread but i must not die. how?

Comment: If you're just getting started in threading/multithreading (it seems you are), best to do some research - whatever works best for you, that might be books, articles, tutorials, ... You could read through these as a starting point: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will solve your problem.  Set it to ThreadPriority.BelowNormal (or Lowest) and any thread that is started by other processes on your machine will get scheduled ahead of your worker thread.  It notably keeps any program you use interactively more responsive.  The consequence is that your worker thread can get starved for cpu time when another process is burning cpu.  It will still run occasionally, just not very often.

In general, avoid starting more threads than you have cpu cores.  Environment.ProcessorCount.  The threadpool scheduler already does this automatically, but doesn't pay attention to other processes.

Comment: To avoid confusing future readers (because OP's question is ambiguously worded):  The "it" to set to a low priority, should NOT be your main thread that is running the UI (the message loop). After you have confirmed that a particular thread is making the UI "laggy", and you have followed advice elsewhere to make sure that thread yields control when it can, then try lowering the priority of that thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing general "slowing" and "lag" then boosting the priority of any individual thread is only going to make things worse.

It depends exactly how your app is structured, but if you have some heavy processing going on and it's using enough processor time to have a negative impact on the rest of the system then you have two main options:

1. Reduce the priority of the processing threads so that activity in the rest of the system takes priority.
2. Introduce artificial breaks in the processing thread. Typically this is done by regularly sending the thread to sleep or yielding to other threads or an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be increasing the priority on threads that require a higher priority within the system, not just because they are running slowly. Priority means that your thread should be considered more important than other threads. In this case, I don't think that this is the case.

If you lower the priority, then you will probably find it appears to run slower, as other tasks may take the processing time.

What you need to do is reasses your processing, possibly add threads ( or more threads ), or consider how the processing can be improved in other ways. Prioirty is not the answer.